# pdftk: multiple page ranges

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I want to grab a few pages from a large (600+ pgs) document using pdftk. How can I do this?

example: suppose the pages I need are 300, 307-310, and 315-318 from a file named "bloated.pdf". This doesn't seem to work:

```
pdftk A=bloated.pdf cat A300,307-310,315-318 output slim.pdf
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
pdftk A=bloated.pdf cat A300 A307-310 A315-318 A600-end output slim.pdf
```